# Como ordenar una colección de objetos en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel, ordenamiento

Estoy buscando tambien la mejor manera de hacer esto dependiendo mi ejemplo que paso a detallar.

Basicamente lo que hace mi controlador, es traer el nombre categoria seleccionada( desde un navbar), y mediante un scope, traigo la categoria en forma de objeto. Luego por medio de la relacion 1:M traigo todo los articulos de esa categoria. Y bueno  lo termina mostrando

Mi tema es que me los ordena por id de manera ascendente. Y siendo articulo me muestra el mas antiguo primero. Lo que necesitaría seria ordenarlos de forma descendentes para q me muestre primero los mas nuevos

```
public function searchCategoria($nombre){

    $categoria = Categoria::searchCategoria($nombre)->first();
    $articulos = $categoria->articulos()->paginate(5);

    $articulos->each(function($articulos){
        $articulos->categoria;
        $articulos->imagen;
    });
    dd($articulos);
    return view('front/index')->with("articulos",$articulos);
}
```

Este es el resultado de ese dd de $articulos

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#249 ▼
#total: 1
#lastPage: 1
#items: Collection {#250 ▼
#items: array:1 [▼
  0 => Articulo {#252 ▶}
]
}
#perPage: 5
#currentPage: 1
#path: "http://emap.net/categorias/Noticias"
#query: []
#fragment: null
#pageName: "page"
}
```

En mi poca experiencia en PHP y mas en Laravel, aun no use algun metodo de ordenamiento. Pero me interesa saber si hay alguna mejor solucion, mediante un orderBy en la relacion dentro del modelo o algo asi. Porque por lo menos en Java el sort siempre es el ultimo recurso.

La otra que se me ocurrio basicamente es traer la categoria, obtener su id y buscar todo los articulos con un where y un orderBy. No estaria haciendo uso de la relacion, seria mas practico pero no se si lo mas correcto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que ya tienes la colección, yo utilizaría el método `sortByDesc()` (aplicable a colecciones) con la fecha o el campo deseado antes de aplicar la paginación, sin embargo no tengo como probarlo en este momento y no recuerdo si ya es una colección o aún un query en ese punto.

Colección:

```
$articulos = $categoria->articulos();
$ordenados = $articulos->sortByDesc('created_at')->paginate(5);

$ordenados->values()->all();
```

Query builder:

```
$articulos = $categoria->articulos()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);
```

Comment: vos sabes que probe la solucion de Query antes de armar el post. Pero con id y no asi, sino, despues de obtener los articulos en la instancia. De la forma $articulos->orderBy(...) y me daba error. Ahora lo probe asi, e incluso con id y anduvo perfecto. No se cual habra sido el problema